# Making Divs Draggable But Contained Using jsPlumb With YUI

Tags: yui, draggable, jsplumb

I'm trying to use jsPlumb with the YUI framework to make some divs draggable and connected. However, I find when I try to make the divs draggable but contained within their parent, using:

```
jsPlumb.draggable("window2", {
    containment:"parent"
});
```

the div is still draggable outside the bounds of its parent. If I set the parent's css to "overflow: hidden" I won't see the div when it's dragged beyond the parent's bounds but I'll still see the connector to the div, which looks really awkward. 
To see this all in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xXYwX/3/
Does anyone know if there is a way to use jsPlumb's draggable function with YUI and still restrict the movement of the draggable div?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First make the div draggable using jsPlumb:

```
jsPlumb.draggable("window2");
```

Then add necessary jsPlumb end points:

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint("window2", { ----});
```

Then add the HTML draggable like

```
$('#window2').draggable({
    containment: 'parent'
});
```

Its working for me..

Answer (score 0):

No, it seems not possible with the yui version of jsPlumb. The 'dd-constrain' module is missing and i found no way to plug this module in, because you can't get access to the Y.DD.Drag object.

You can send a feature request to the creator or do a pull request on github.
Here is a plain yui example with a constrained drag:
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/constrained-drag.html

Answer (score 0):

make your container overflow: visible in css