# jsplumb drag and drop to a specific div area

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jsplumb

I created a flowchart with jsplumb based on the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kika001/ZWR6y/)

However I am trying to make blocks only draggable in a specific area that I created with a div baliser like :

```
    <div id="drop_here" style="height:100%; width:50%"></div>
```

I tried many options but could not run. Some one can help me? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30498041/5067372), you can use the `draggable` command from [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) doing something like this:

```
jsPlumb.draggable('#cool_object');
$('#cool_object').draggable({ containment: $('#drop_here')});
```

More info on the `draggable` command [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it straight, you want to limit the draggable objects into a div, right? If that's your problem you can solve it using `containment` when creating the objects:

```
var YOUR_OBJECT = jsPlumb.getSelector("#OBJECT_ID");

jsPlumb.draggable(YOUR_OBJECT , {
    containment: "parent"
});
```